# Best way to store country and city information

Tags: database-design, performance, query-performance

I always wondered what is more efficient between two. There is one "main" table where I store all user related informations. Also, there are two more tables, `country` and `city` tables. `city` table contains column **country_id** so I can relate to which country this city belongs.

Now, the main question : should I store only **city_id** in user table and query for country name using **country_id** from `city` table or to store both, **city_id** and **country_id** ?

======

Other thing is related to counting. If have some fourth table, like `message`, and I store ID of user who send message, ID of user who receive message, text, etc. Now, if I want to know how many messages some user sent, I can query for messages where sender=ID and count rows, but I used another approach. I created column **count** in user table and whenever user send message, I increase this number. Is this approach good and if no, is the first one efficient since that table can have billions of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Countries are relatively stable so it is easy to have a countries table.  City names can be duplicated multiple times within a country.   Maintaining the city table may be difficult for a couple of reasons.

- Some cities have different spellings in different languages.
- Some countries have multiple cities with the same name.  These are likely in different states or provinces.

You may want to allow free format for the city and keep it in the user table.  Otherwise, investigate adding a state/province table.  You will still need to deal with how to add new cities as needed.

If you index the sender, the count can be done on the index.  This can be extremely efficient for smaller counts.  Updating the user table for each message will increase the log data volume, and increase the cost of saving each message.  It is also error prone, and can lead to deadlocks if you are not consistent in the order the accesses are done.  De-normalizing the model should be done only after determining you have a performance problem.

A query like `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM message WHERE sender=?ID` is likely better than maintaining a count.

Comment: what is your suggestion regarding city table ? for second part, did I understand well, you suggest I should stick with querying messages and counting result rows ?

Comment: @BTestQ I have updated my response.  City tables are difficult to work with.  You will need to determine your requirements.  The timezone data provides a large city for each country.  Stick with querying messages until you find it is too slow. (Use an index.)

Comment: I still have to know from which city is my user. It should be standard form (like the one when you create email account), user choose country and based on that, city combo will be populated. Now, my only concern is should I store both IDs or only one since I can determine country from city. I know there are city's with the same name but in table, they have their ID's and country ID so they won't be mixed.

Comment: @BTestQ As long as you don't need to disambiguate multiple cities in the same country, you can use a Cities table.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_%28USA%29 for a list of states with Paris in them.  If you allow users to enter cities you are likely to end up with Parsi, paris, Paris, and other variations.  If you don't, you will get bogus data.